# Moving player on Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a map class, which is an Array of 100 Strings

```
public class map{
    [...]
    public void movePlayer(String entrada){
    if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){
        move = -10;
    }
    else if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
        move = 10;
    }
    else if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
        move = 1;
    }
    else if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
        move = -1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < mapa.length; i++){
        if (mapa[i].equals("P")){
            int moved = i+move;
            mapa[moved] = "P";
        }
    }
}
```

The main looks a little like this

```
String[] mapa = map.getMap();
    mapa[0] = "T";
    mapa[99] = "P";
    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
            if (i == 9 || i == 19 || i == 29 || i == 39 || i == 49 || i == 59 || i == 69 || i == 79 || i == 89 || i == 99){
                System.out.println(mapa[i]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(mapa[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Entre o movimento:");
        map.movePlayer(read.nextLine());
        mapa = map.getMap();
    }
```

It runs like this: A map with random chars are printed, some are normal floors some are traps
EXAMPLE

```
T##_______
^__@__*^@_
@#^^#_#___
_*^^^#^^@^
^^_#_^____
^#_^#___##
*@^_^_____
^@##_^__^#
#_@^##^#**
#@^^_#@_#P
Enter movement:w
T##_______
^__@__*^@_
@#^^#_#___
_*^^^#^^@^
^^_#_^____
^#_^#___##
*@^_^_____
^@##_^__^#
#_@^##^#*P
#@^^_#@_#P
Enter movement: w
T##_______
^__@__*^@_
@#^^#_#___
_*^^^#^^@^
^^_#_^____
^#_^#___##
*@^_^_____
^@##_^__^P
#_@^##^#*P
#@^^_#@_#P
```

How can I make the program to print the place where the Player originally was with the previous char it had, in this case a blank space in position [99] and a "*" in position [89]? Thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of tracking the player inside the map, you can leave the map unchanged and just track the player's position.

```
int playerpos = 99;
for (int j = 0; j<10; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        if (playerpos == i)
          System.out.print("P");
        else
          System.out.print(mapa[i]);
        if (i %10 == 9){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Then your `movePlayer` method just changes the `playerpos` variable.

Comment: Good idea. There's a syntax error in line 7(mapa instead of map)

Comment: From OP's code, mapa is an instance of map, so that was deliberate.  Doesn't match the `map.length` in the for loop though, but that matches the original code so maybe it's a static constant he's pulling.

Answer (score 0):

before player's movement you need to store data from the target cell, like this

```
int moved = i+move;
previousChar = mapa[moved]; // store replaced symbol
mapa[moved] = "P";
```

so, during next move you need to restore original char in old position, it could look like this:

```
int moved = i+move;
mapa[i] = previousChar; // restore original symbol at current player's location
previousChar = mapa[moved]; // preserve symbol at new player's location
mapa[moved] = "P"; // move player to new location
```

don't forget to init previousChar before very first move

Answer (score 0):

As Lashane is saying, use a variable to store the overriden char for later assignment:

```
public class map{
    [...]

    this.init(function() {
        last_squarechar = INIT_SQUARECHAR
        [...]
    });

    public void movePlayer(String entrada) {
        if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){
            move = -10;
        }
        else if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            move = 10;
        }
        else if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
            move = 1;
        }
        else if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
            move = -1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < mapa.length; i++){
        if (mapa[i].equals("P")){
            int moved = i+move;
            mapa[i] = last_squarechar
            last_squarechar = mapa[moved]
            mapa[moved] = "P";
        }
    }
}
```